# mysql COUNT() in php

Tags: mysql, count

I have the following database:

```
Drager ||  Price
----------------
LP     ||  €16
CD     ||  €9 
LP     ||  €21
S      ||  €12
```

I want to count the "Drager" and make a table that looks like this:

```
Drager ||  Number  ||  Price
LP     ||  2       ||  €37
CD     ||  1       ||  €9
S      ||  1       ||  €12
```

My question now is: how can I count all the "dragers"?

I got this query but how can I count them separetaly?:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(Medium) FROM platen";
```

And how can I get the total price?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: What do you mean count them separately?

Comment: So I can count how many LP's there are in Medium and how many cd's there are etc so I get like LP : 2, CD : 1, S : 1 back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be as simple as:

```
SELECT  Drager
      , COUNT(*) AS Number_of_Dragers
      , SUM(price) AS Price_of_Dragers
FROM    your_table
GROUP BY Drager
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your looking for;

```
$query = "SELECT drager, COUNT(drager),SUM(price) FROM platen GROUP BY drager";
```